# First-chance exception at msvcr120d.dll without stack. How to find a reason?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a complicated project and sometimes I have this weird rte:

> First-chance exception at 0x000007FED6B4AA69 (msvcr120d.dll) in
>   DxTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x0000000005CD0000. Unhandled exception at 0x000007FED6B4AA69
>   (msvcr120d.dll) in DxTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x0000000005CD0000.

It appears randomly and I don't know how to reproduce it. The stack trace have only one line:

[image]

I have two places where I'm calling memcpy() and I wrapped them in try catch block. But anyway I have this exception without stack trace.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: I'm afraid that the inability to reproduce the error makes this question unanswerable.

Comment: ``memcpy`` doesn't thow exceptions, you better check its arguments before call. Also you can put a breakpoint before ``memcpy`` calls to take a look at memory you're working with.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev That's interesting. I can't find in documentation that it's doesn't throw. And you were right - the problem was in arguments - I mistyped.